# VS Code Project Folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Where should I keep my projects? There is no special folder in VS Code. Do I have to create it? Where? Maybe **.vscode** folder is the best option? Or this will be automatically removed after you uninstall/reinstall the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep them in the default location:

```
%USERPROFILE%\sourcerepos
```

Or create another folder and name it `Projects` (for example) in another drive.

Comment: The root of User Profile directory would be ideal option, but there are already too many folders (16). I would not like to add one more. It's easy to get confused when you already have the following folders there: .conda, .idlerc .pylint.d .vscode. Downloads Favourites Pictures Contacts My Documents My Video My Music My Etc Another one My Thing My Stuff and Finally - *My Projects*?

Comment: For me, my favorite location is in another drive. The `D` drive, labeled `Data`, is used for data, and `C` drive I use for `OS` and `Apps`. You can also redirect the system folders `Music`, `Videos`, and `Pictures` to the `D` drive @michael.

Comment: I have the drive with label `Data` too. Thank you for idea. Previously, I'd used it only for old archived projects @Toni.

Answer (score 1):

Any folder can be your project. That’s why there’s the “Open folder” command. How to best organize your project inside that folder depends on what type of project it is.

Comment: I'm talking not about a single (separate) project but about the projects as a whole (collectively). In what directory do you keep all of these folders?